# find the minimization of the dfa

Tags: automata, finite-automata, compilers

so this is the question , I have to minimize this DFA

[image]

this is How I did it

[image]

but when I checked for answers , this is what it was,
[image]
can someone please explain to me what mistake I made? I have been wondering about this for past 2 days

Answer (score 1):

None of these two automata is correct. The main reason is the following:

**You forgot the INITIAL STATE and the FINAL STATE.**

Please, don't forget to indicate those, this is a very common mistake, but without those, a correct automaton becomes an incorrect automaton.

Otherwise, the automaton seems correct, and the automaton in the "answer" is indeed not minimal. However, your method to find equivalences between states seems unclear (I doubt it would work for a bigger automaton).

Exercise: minimize the following automaton:

[image]